# error: package com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier does not exist when deploying to target

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, google-play-services, google-nearby

I'm a bit new to the Gradle build system. My app already had some working integrations with Google Play Services, including the Ads library. I'm trying to add the Android Nearby service to my build.gradle, but the import for the ads library no longer works specifically *after* I added in the Nearby library.

In my build.gradle:

```
dependency {
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:$rootProject.ext.playServicesLibraryVersion"
}
```

`playServicesLibraryVersion` is 15.0.1, which is [the latest](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). The project builds successfully, but the errors arise specifically when I'm deploying to target. My target device is running Android P and I'm using Android Studio 3.1.2.

If I add `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$rootProject.ext.playServicesLibraryVersion"` I get a Multiple Dex error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your entire manifest?

Comment: Could you post your full build.gradle dependencies as well as the error text?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help, but I resolved the issue after some hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Update: issue was resolved when I did a clean build, invalidated cache, and used `api` instead of `implementation` in the build.gradle. I added both libraries to my dependencies.